# On the equivalence relation induced by an arbitrary map

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

The book I am reading (Szekeres's *A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics*) makes the following claim:

> More generally, any map $φ : X → Y$ defines an equivalence relation $R$ on $X$ by $aRb$ iff $φ(a) = φ(b)$. The equivalence classes defined by $R$ are precisely the inverse images of the singleton subsets of Y,
> $$X/R = \{φ^{−1}({y}) | y ∈ Y \},$$
> and the map $ψ : Y → X/R$ defined by $ψ(y) = φ^{−1}(\{y\})$ is one-to-one, for if $ψ(y) = ψ(y′)$ then y = y′ – pick any element $x ∈ ψ(y) = ψ(y′)$ and we must have $φ(x) = y = y′$.

I think the equating of $X/R$ to $\{φ^{−1}({y}) | y ∈ Y \}$ is a bit sloppy here. In particular, unless $\varphi$ is onto, we will have $\emptyset \in \{φ^{−1}({y}) | y ∈ Y \}$, and yet $\emptyset \notin X/R$. Of course the rest of the definition would need to be modified too since $\psi$ does not make sense as it stands (without $\varphi$ onto). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Here he has to suppose $\phi$ surjective or $X/R=\{\phi^{-1}(y) | y\in Im(\phi)\}$

Comment: Awesome, thank you! @FedericoFallucca